# Visual Studio 2010: set hide a Dialog box Setup Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project

I have a setup project in visual studio 2010, I add 2 dialog box, in the first step, the first dialog box has 2 radio buttons, if the first radio button is selected i need set hide the next dialog box or i want remove the second dialog box in the run time, thanks

Comment: Not an answer, but you should know that Visual Studio 2012 does not support Setup project types. So perhaps you should consider not investing your time too heavily? Consider WiX: http://wixtoolset.org/ instead.

Comment: thans Daniel, i will study on WIX